# Multiple inputs with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, user-input, joptionpane

I need to write a program that helps determine a budget for "peer advising" the following year based on the current year. The user will be asked for the peer advisor names and their highest earned degree in order to determine how much to pay them. I am using a `JOptionPane` instead of `Scanner` and I'm also using an `ArrayList`.

Is there a way for the user to input both the name and the degree all in one input and store them as two different values, or am I going to have to have two separate input dialogs? Example: storing the name as "Name1" and the degree as "Degree1 in order to calculate their specific pay.

Also, I am using an `ArrayList` but I know that the list will need to hold a maximum of six (6) elements, is there a better method to do what I am trying to do?

Here is what I had down before I started thinking about this, if it's necessary.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PeerTutoring
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> tutors = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            String line = null;
            line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter tutor name and their highest earned degree.");
            String[] result = line.split("\\s+");
            String name = result[0];
            String degree = result[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use JOptionPane or can you use a scanner?

Comment: We are required to use JOptionPane. After reading my book, I feel like I could use a Multidimensional Array. Is that possible?

Comment: see the answer I provided, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Is there a way for the user to input both the name and the degree all
 in one input, but store them as two different values."*

Yes. You can ask the user to enter input separated with space for example, and split the result:

```
String[] result = line.split("\\s+"); //Split according to space(s)
String name = result[0];
String degree = result[1];
```

Now you have the input in two variables.

*"I decided to use ArrayList but I know the number of names that will be inputed (6), is there a more appropriate array method to use?"*

`ArrayList` is fine, but if the length is fixed, use can use a fixed size array.

---

### Regarding OP update

You're doing it wrong, this should be like this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>(6);
String[] splitted;
String line;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
    line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter tutor name and their highest earned degree.");
    splitted = line.split("\\s+");
    list.add(splitted);
}

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(list.get(i))); //Will print all 6 pairs
```

You should create an `ArrayList` that contains a String array that will represent the input (since the user enters pair as an input). Now, all what you have to do is to insert this pair to the `ArrayList`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Anyway to display the list in one JOptionPane.showMessageDialog instead of six separate printlns?

Comment: Iterate on the ArrayList and print the values manually or use `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(list.get(i)).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));` and please accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is store the input from you JOptionPane in a String, and then split the String into an array to store the name and degree entered. For example:

```
String value = null;
value =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter tutor name and 
                 their highest earned degree.");

String[] tokens = value.split(" ");//if you input name followed by space followed by degree, this splits the input by the space between them
System.out.println(tokens[0]);//shows the name
System.out.println(tokens[1]);//shows the degree
```

Now you can use `tokens[0]` to add the name to your List.

Comment: This really helps. If I wanted to let the user input the name and degree in separate dialogs, how would I do that? For example, let them input the name and degree, and then after they hit ok,  let them do the same thing over again with a different name and degree. Do I just need to set up a loop?

Comment: Yes just set up a loop. Also if you found the answer helpful you can tick it as the main answer :-)